# Who was Obito going to revive?

Tags: naruto

I just watched the recent episode (391) and just prior to Obito being taken over by Black Zetsu, he seemed to have acknowledged his sins and was planning on using Rinne Rebirth - but for whom? It certainly wasn't for Madara because Black Zetsu wouldn't have gotten involved. Jiraya was on his mind, so was it him? Or was he planning on reviving all of the ninja who died during the war?

Comment: My guess is that he wanted to do the exact same thing that Pain made to revive the people on Konoha Village. It could not be Jiraya because when Pain revived everybody on the village, he specifically said that he cannot revive Jiraya because in order for the jutsu to work, the death must be recent.

Comment: @scubaFun there is no need for the death to be recent, otherwise Madara couldn't be revived, then you know the series has no purpose!

Comment: @krishna - Itachi's fan, it makes sense what you said, both on your comment and answer, I always thought that Pain was unable to revive Jiraya because of what I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obito was trying to revive all the people he killed in battle, the way same way as Nagato did.From [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha_Arises)

> Obito attempts to amend his mistakes by using the Samsara of Heavenly
>   Life Technique to revive those he killed, noting he had finally
>   understand why Nagato betrayed him.

For your question why Nagato didn't revive Jiraiya... My guess is the dead people will
 be revived from where their dead body is,

> Since Jiraiya's body was far too deep in ocean that even Kabuto can't reach to
>   collect his DNA, it would be waste to revive him. Even after reviving
>   he will die because of water pressure. So Nagato didn't try to revive
>   Jiraiya.

It is also mentioned in [Jiraiya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya#Legacy)'s wikia page

> Later on, Kabuto revealed that he attempted to retrieve Jiraiya's body
>   to bring him back through Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation, but
>   it was far too deep in the ocean for him to reach without being
>   crushed by the water pressure.

Comment: Tell your reasonings in comment, why you are downvoting the answer...

Comment: If dead people are going to be revived from where their dead body is, then how come people came alive from the hidden leaf village crushed by 'Shinra Tensei'. Their bodies also should be crushed inside, and if you revive them, they'll die in suffocation. Your second&third references are about 'Edo Tensei' only, it has nothing todo with 'Rinne Tensei'.